# AngularJS passing data between 2 functions in the same controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, return

I have a controller which has multiple functions. I need those functions to share some data. For instance, in the code below, my **signin** function calls the `system_connect` function from which I want to return http response data back to signin.

Because both these functions are in the same controller, I assumed putting data into `$scope.formData` in the `system_connect` function, the same data was be accessible and readable in the *signin* function - but it isn't working.

```
headlessQS.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http', '$cookieStore', function($scope, $log, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http, $cookieStore){

    //        signin / register function
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.signin = function(){
        console.log('Signin: ');

        $scope.system_connect($scope.formData);
        console.log('Testing Scope.user: ');
        console.log( $scope.connection_response );

        $location.path('/');

    }

    //  drupal system connect
    $scope.system_connect = function(formData){
        console.info('System Connect ...');

        $http.post('http://mysite/angularjs-headless/api/v1/system/connect', 
            {
                'username': formData.username,
                'password': formData.password
            }, 
            {
                'Content-type' : 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            }
        )
        .then(
//            successCallback,
            function(response){
              console.log('Working ...');
                $log.info(response);
                $scope.formData = response;
            },
//            errorCallback
            function(response){
                console.log('NOT Working ...');
                $log.info(response);
                $scope.formData = response;
            }
        );        
    }
}]);
```

How might I pass data between two functions in a controller?

### Update

Thanks to *Sébastien Temprado* answer below, I'm beginning to see the light. However, when I implemented the promise, I encountered a problem when I tried checking the contents of `$scope.formData`. The error is as follows:

```
(anonymous) @ include.preload.js:628
app.js:39 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Resulting from the following code:

```
headlessQS.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http', '$cookieStore', function($scope, $log, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http, $cookieStore){

//    console.debug( $cookieStore.get('user_session') );


    //        re-direct to the sign-in / register form
    $scope.signin = function(){
        var promise = $scope.system_connect($scope.connection_response);
        promise.then({
            console.log("formData:"+JSON.stringify($scope.connection_response));
        });
    }

    //  drupal system connect
    $scope.system_connect = function(formData){
        console.info('System Connect ...');

//        $http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        var promise = $http.post('http://mysite/QuestionsGenerator/angularjs-headless/api/v1/system/connect', 
            {
                'username': formData.username,
                'password': formData.password
            }, 
            {
                'Content-type' : 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            }
        )
        .then(
//            successCallback,
            function(response){
              console.log('Working ...');
                $log.info(response);
                $scope.connection_response = response;
            },
//            errorCallback
            function(response){
                console.log('NOT Working ...');
                $log.info(response);
                $scope.connection_response = response;
            }
        );

        return promise;

    }
}]);
```

Line **39** is the `console.log("formData:"+JSON.stringify($scope.formData));` code. It's the same even if JSON.stringify is taken out and I attempt to log *$scope.formData*

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. function() is missing : promise.then(function(){....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call $http.post(), it's asynchronous (the success callback isn't called immediately) and the execution continue : no more code in system_connect() so it goes back to the signin function().
At this moment, $scope.formData is still empty.

Then, when you get the response of the post, the success callback is called, $scope.formData is modified but the signin function() has already been executed!

To solve this problem, you have to use a promise :

```
$scope.signin = function(){
    var promise = $scope.system_connect($scope.formData);
    promise.then(function(){
        console.log("formData:"+JSON.stringify($scope.formData));    
    });
}

$scope.system_connect = function(formData){
    var promise = $http.post('http://mysite/angularjs-headless/api/v1/system/connect', 
        {
            'username': formData.username,
            'password': formData.password
        }, 
        {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
        }
    )
    .then(
        function(response){
          console.log('Success callback');
          $scope.formData = response;
        },
        function(response){
            console.log('errorCallback');
            $scope.formData = response;
        }
    ); 
    return promise;       
}
```

**Note**

$http.post returns a promise which is used in the signin function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I thought it might have something to do with the asynchronous nature of the function calls ... but I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." error on the  " console.log("formData:"+JSON.stringify($scope.formData));" line

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated